# Reading XML data in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've been trying out how to make databases in XML. I've successfully written data, like below:

```
<Employees>
    <Worker>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <FirstName>Ilan</FirstName>
        <LastName>Berlinbluv</LastName>
        <Salary>5000</Salary>
    </Worker>
</Employees>
```

The problem is that when I try to read using this code:

```
    string writePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%") + @"\Desktop";
    string writeFile = writePath + @"\Employees.xml";

    using (XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(writeFile))
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
            if (read.IsStartElement())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: read.Name = {0}", read.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: read.Value = {0}", read.Value);
                switch (read.Name)
                {
                    case "Employees":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start <Employees> master element");
                        break;
                    case "Employee":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start <Employee> element");
                        break;
                    case "Worker":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start <Worker> element");
                        break;
                    case "ID":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start reading <ID> element");
                        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + read.Value.Trim());
                        break;
                    case "FirstName":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start reading <FirstName> element");
                        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + read.Value.Trim());
                        break;
                    case "LastName":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start reading <LastName> element");
                        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + read.Value.Trim());
                        break;
                    case "Salary":
                        Console.WriteLine("Start reading <Salary> element");
                        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + read.Value.Trim());
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't properly read values, whenever it says `Start reading <Salary> element` and then `Contains:`, it doesn't show any value, but there should be a value: 5000. Is it a syntax error, where I need it to be like:

```
<ID>
1
</ID>
```

I've been doing the [dotnetperls tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader) but to no avail.

Comment: cant you use LINQ to xml?

Comment: See [`XmlReader.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.value.aspx) – a XML element node (which is where your reader is at if `IsStartElement()` is `true`) does not have a value. You need to get the text **inside** the element, using [`XmlReader.ReadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readstring.aspx) I think.

Comment: LINQ to XML or another DOM-flavoured API is also not a bad suggestion if you don't need the performance of a streaming approach.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to write code to read XML documents. Use the built-in XML serializer instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
You can read XML like: 
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(Server.MapPath("\\foldername\\" + "filename.xml"));
 XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Employees//Worker/Salary");
 Response.Write(node.InnerText.ToString());

 This way, you can get 5000 as Salary.
```

Comment: Yes, but I have a lot more of values:  
`<Employees>
<Worker>
<ID>1</ID>
<FirstName>Ilan</FirstName>
<LastName>Berlinbluv</LastName>
<Salary>5000</Salary>
</Worker>
<Worker>
<ID>2</ID>
<FirstName>Noam</FirstName>
<LastName>Inbar</LastName>
<Salary>4000</Salary>
</Worker>
<Worker>
<ID>3</ID>
<FirstName>Guy</FirstName>
<LastName>Horwitz</LastName>
<Salary>3500</Salary>
</Worker>
<Worker>
<ID>4</ID>
<FirstName>Ilan</FirstName>
<LastName>Cohen</LastName>
<Salary>2000</Salary>
</Worker>
</Employees>`

Comment: The you can do : XElement employees= XElement.Load("filename.xml");
        foreach (XElement name in country.Elements("Worker").Elements("Salary"))
        {
            Response.Write(name.Value);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XSD tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) to use the serializer. First create a XML schema and then create a class from the XML schema. Then you can read the XML directly to an object:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="xml"></param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Deserialize<T>(XmlNode xml)
    {
        // Assuming xml is an XML document containing a serialized object.
        XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xml);

        // When we get the xml, it is usually a sub element that can have a different name, than the type name. Therefore look for the name
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        object obj = ser.Deserialize(reader);

        // Then you just need to cast obj into whatever type it is eg:
        return (T)obj;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes without removing namespace and using the specified encoding
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <param name="encoding"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">When the object can not be serialized to xml</exception>
    public static XmlDocument Serialize<T>(T obj, Encoding encoding)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = GetSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, encoding))
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            doc.Load(stream);
            return doc;
        }
    }
```

You might want to edit the XML schema before you create a class to ensure that the types are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to get acces to specific node of XML file is to use LINQ.

```
string writePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%") + @"\Desktop";
string writeFile = writePath + @"\Employees.xml";

XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(writeFile)
```

then if you want to read all elements inside your Worker element

```
var queryResult = from x in xmlDocument.Root.Element("Worker").Elements() select x;
foreach (var item in queryResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Or if you want to process all Worker elements separtelly then simply cast query result to list

```
var queryResult = (from x in xmlDocument.Root.Element("Worker").Elements() select x).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Start reading <ID> element");
Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + queryResult[0]);

Console.WriteLine("Start reading <FirstName> element");
Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + queryResult[1]);

Console.WriteLine("Start reading <LastName> element");
Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + queryResult[2]);

Console.WriteLine("Start reading <Salary> element");
Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + queryResult[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that it's always easier to work with XML when you serialize to and from business objects.

```c#
[Serializable]
public class Employees
{
    private List<Worker> _Workers;
    [XmlArray]
    public List<Worker> Workers
    {
        get { return _Workers; }
        set { _Workers = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Worker
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    // etc.


    public void SerializeToXML(string outputFolderLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!outputFolderLocation.EndsWith('\\'))
            {
                outputFolderLocation += "\\";
            }

            //Create our own namespaces for the output
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            //Add an empty namespace and empty value
            ns.Add("", "");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Worker));
            string outpath = outputFolderLocation + "FileName-" + DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString() + ".xml";
            XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(outpath, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, this, ns);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error serializing to XML", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also tidy up your XML by making values XML Attributes instead of nodes. To do this you change the property to this:

```
[XmlAttribute("ID-Value")]
public Int32 ID { get; set; }
// would serialise like this <worker ID-Value="1"></worker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use read.InnerText instead of read.Value.

Once you understand how all of this works, I'd recommend using the built in XML handling functions.  You'll save yourself a lot of headaches.